# Django OperationalError: no such column: on pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, operationalerror

First, I was able to fix the ImportError. I figured out that it was because the Django version of pythonanywhere is not updated, So I upgraded Django on pythonanywhere from 1.x.x to 2.0.9.

The error came out like this:

> ImportError at /
>       cannot import name 'path'

```
django version: 1.x.x
python version: 3.6.6
```

and, unfortunately, my app gave me another error:

> OperationalError at /
>       no such column: blog_post.published_date
>       Request Method:   GET
>       Request URL:  http://*.pythonanywhere.com/
>       Django Version:   2.0.9
>       Exception Type:   OperationalError
>       Exception Value:
>
>       no such column: blog_post.published_date
>       Exception Location:   /home/*/my-first-blog/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py
>   in execute, line 303
>       Python Executable:    /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
>       Python Version:   3.6.6

I thought this error occurred because of some database, so I tried `migrate` or `makemigrations` on pythonanywhere, but I could not fix it still.

So, is there anyone who knows how to fix this database?

**Here is my `model.py`:**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**here is the output of `python manage.py showmigrations`:**

```
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
 [X] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length
blog
 [X] 0001_initial
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
```

Comment: Can you post your `blog_post` model in the question above?

Comment: To help debug your issue you could inspect your database with the sqlite3 command line tool. see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_commands.htm

Comment: Can your post the output of `python manage.py showmigrations`?

Comment: If this is a newly migrated database, I would suggest you get rid of it and migrate again.

Comment: @waqasgard okay I will try.

Comment: @RedCricket I added out of the command.

Comment: The problem as I see has to be with the database and django migrations. The Post object inside the `blog` has the attribute that django's trying to find. The migrations haven't been correctly applied to the database. Now considering the history of migrations, I do not know what's going wrong unless I can look around your database which I'm assuming is an `sqlite`. Can you afford to get rid of the database?

Comment: @waqasgard It works! Thank you for your kindness!

Comment: Great! But please remember this is the least recommended solution as it has lead to a complete data loss.

Comment: @waqasgard Okay. only for new app, my test data are gone.

Comment: You are on django 1.something and path was introduced in django 2. Put your `app/urls.py` in question

Comment: @ans2human He'd mentioned he'd tried upgrading his Django to 2.x

Comment: @waqasgard, i see you helped him so draft the answer and get it checked. Happy stacking.

Comment: @IvoryTheCat Please upvote my answer below and mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: @ans2human I just tried that already, and the error was solved. anyway, thank you for comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem as I see has to be with the database and django migrations.

The `Post` object inside the blog has the attribute that django's trying to find. The migrations haven't been correctly applied to the database.

Now considering the history of migrations, I do not know what's going wrong unless I can look around your database which I'm assuming is an sqlite.

One way to resolve this if you're having a newly constructed database is to get rid of the database and do the following:

- Delete all the migrations from `app/migrations` directory
- `python manage.py makemigrations`
- `python manage.py migrate`

Also, try to avoid `sqlite` as much as possible. The same migrations that ran on an `sqlite` db might be erroneous on Postgres or MySQL database which are more production grade databases.

**NOTE**: Please understand that this would lead to a complete data loss. Hence, try this only if you can afford to compromise on the existing/test data.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to refresh your production server after every migration if you want the changes to take effect